# Tools for Rasch model analysis with python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been doing data analysis in R, and I'm contemplating switching over to python+pandas. However, I depend on the Rasch family of models (rating scale and partial credit) in R's eRm package, and I've been unable to determine whether an equivalent python package exists. All I've found is the [edstan-python](https://github.com/danielcfurr/edstan-python) package on GitHub, and I'm not seeing much there to indicate that it is complete, robust, widely-adopted, or even maintained.

Does anyone know if I can do polytomous Rasch modeling in python? *Thanks...*

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing and all I'm seeing is a note in the `catsim` package suggesting that that package can be used to meet all your Rasch needs (assuming you understand the relevant equations well enough): https://pythonhosted.org/catsim/introduction.html